# Remove root element from a heap tree

Tags: haskell

How do I remove the smallest element of an heap tree?

This element is at the root of the tree. If I remove that, I'm left with two independent subtrees.

```
data Heap a = Empty
            | Node a (Heap a) (Heap a)
```

The type of the function is:

```
removeMin :: Heap a -> (a, Heap a)
```

It should return the tree and the minimum removed.

Should I make an auxiliary function to build a new tree, or is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: I happen to know there are heaps to be found in L.C. Paulson's *ML for the Working Programmer*, including a version of the binary heaps you're talking about. If you want to learn more about heaps in functional programming, I suggest you read *Purely Functional Data Structures*, by Chris Okasaki. He covers leftist heaps, splay heaps, binomial heaps, skew binomial heaps, and bootstrapped heaps (Brodal-Okasaki heaps).

Answer (score 4):

Your type, as written, raises some questions:

- Q: What's the output from `removeMin Empty`?

  A: You can't produce an `a` from nothing, so the result should be wrapped in `Maybe`.
- Q: If I've put `(+)`, `(-)` and `(*)` in a `Heap (Int -> Int -> Int)`, which one should be returned by `removeMin`?

  A: Not all data types have an ordering (notably, functions lack one), so it makes sense to require that the data type have an `Ord` instance.

So the updated type becomes:

```
removeMin :: Ord a => Heap a -> Maybe (a, Heap a)
```

Now consider it case by case:

1. `Empty` has no min element:

   ```
   removeMin Empty = Nothing
   ```
2. If one branch is empty, the remaining heap is the other branch

   ```
   removeMin (Node a Empty r) = Just (a, r)
   removeMin (Node a l Empty) = Just (a, l)
   ```

   Convince yourself that this works for `Node a Empty Empty`.
3. If neither branch is empty, then the new smallest min element must be the root of one of the branches.

   The branches in the resulting `Heap` are just the branch of the larger element, and the branch of the smaller element, with its minimum removed.

   Fortunately, we already have a helper to remove the minimum from a `Heap`!

   ```
   removeMin (Node a l@(Node la _ _) r@(Node ra _ _)) = Just (a, Node mina maxN minN')
     where (minN, maxN) = if la <= ra then (l,r) else (r,l)
           Just (mina, minN') = removeMin minN
   ```

Now, while this produces a valid heap, it's not necessarily the best algorithm because it's not guaranteed to produce a *balanced* heap.  A poorly balanced heap is no better than a linked list, giving you `O(n)` insertion and deletion times where a balanced heap can give you `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should build an appropriate function to build new tree, but don't worry- it will not perform poorly. GHC can optimize such use cases and this operation could be just as fast as you want (including large, even infinite (recursive) data structures).

I understand you are able to create such auxiliary function by yourself? It is straightforward - anyway, in case of troubles I can write it later.

Comment: I am trying to build the function, if you could provide some hints to guide me i would appreciate very much !

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: After removing the top node, you're left with two heaps. So you need to implement (recursive) *merging* of two heaps, something like

```
merge :: (Ord a) => Heap a -> Heap a -> Heap a
```

You could also implement a monoid instance for `Heap`

```
instance (Ord a) => Monoid (Heap a) where
    mempty = Empty
    mappend = -- the merging function
```